# std::uniform_int_distribution placed into a function or am I using it wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I am a new user of C++ and currently I am trying a challenge on YouTube of making a 1d console prompt game; I am trying to make it so that I have weapons that have different damage ranges and when the console opens it gives a random number between a set range e.g., 40 - 80.

However, when I try to run it to see what I have so far the number generator just keeps giving me the same number over and over again. Now, I am going to take a guess and think that there is something wrong with my seed generator but if I stick the code in the function into main everything runs smoothly. Can **std::mt19937** and **std::uniform_int_distribution** go into function with parameters or am I going about it completely wrong, is the return wrong?

I would post an image but as I am new to stackOverflow and have < 10 rep I am unable to do so.

**Example 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>


// global veriables, health points, Alive status, random number generator and weapon damage values;

//health points
double giantHP = 2000;
double dwarfHP = 140;
double elfHP = 90;
double ironDwarf = 280;
double rydelTheArcher = 180;

// isMainAlive? 
bool isRydelTheArcher = true;
bool isIronDwarf = true;

// random number function 
int rN(int low, int high) 
{
    std::mt19937 seed(time(NULL));
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> attackNum(low, high);

    return attackNum(seed);
}

// weapon damage with min and max values
int club = rN(40, 80); int fist = rN(25, 50);
int arrow = rN(4, 12); int fireArrow = rN(8, 24); int rydelsArrows = rN(8, 24);
int lrgAxe = rN(24, 28); int medAxe = rN(15, 20); int smallAxe = rN(10, 15); int ironDwarfAxe = rN(40, 60);

int main()
{
    /***************************************************************************************************************
    ****************************************************************************************************************
    ** create variables, health points for Giants (attackers), Dwarfs and Elves (defenders) / ( ALT + 0124 = || ),**
    ** damage taken, damage dealt,                                                                                **
    ** speed, attack speed                                                                                        **
    ** and weapons used & range of attack                                                                         **
    ****************************************************************************************************************
    ****************************************************************************************************************/

    // title 
    std::cout << " *** Giants vs Dwarfs and Elves *** " << std::endl;

    // weapon count for loop  
    // testing to see if numbers are being outputted in a random way
    int weaponHitCount = 0; 
    for (weaponHitCount = 0; weaponHitCount < 5000; weaponHitCount++)
    {
        std::cout << "damageDealt: " << club << std::endl
            << fist << std::endl
            << arrow << std::endl
            << fireArrow << std::endl
            << rydelsArrows << std::endl
            << lrgAxe << std::endl
            << medAxe << std::endl
            << smallAxe << std::endl
            << ironDwarfAxe << std::endl
            << "!*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*!" << std::endl;
    }

        std::cin.get();
        std::cin.ignore();

        return 0; 
}



/* (weaponHitCount = 0; weaponHitCount <= 40000; weaponHitCount++)
{
int newWeapon = randomNumber(40, 80);
std::cout << "weapon Damage equals: " << newWeapon << " " << std::endl;
}*/
```

**Example 2:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string> 
#include <ctime>

/** weapon damage with min and max values
**int club = rN(40, 80); int fist = rN(25, 50); // Giants
**int arrow = rN(4, 12); int fireArrow = rN(8, 24); int rydelsArrows = rN(8, 24); // Elves
**int lrgAxe = rN(24, 28); int medAxe = rN(15, 20); int smallAxe = rN(10, 15); int ironDwarfAxe = rN(40, 60);*/ // Dwarves

int rN(int min, int max) // random numbers for each weapon
{
    std::mt19937_64 seeder(time(NULL));
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> club(min = 40, max = 80);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> fist(min = 25, max = 50);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> arrow(min = 4, max = 12);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> fireArrow(min = 8, max = 24);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rydelsArrows(min = 16, max = 26);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> lrgAxe(min = 24, max = 28);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> medAxe(min = 15, max = 20);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> smallAxe(min = 10, max = 15);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> ironDwarfAxe(min = 40, max = 60);

    return club(seeder), fist(seeder),
           arrow(seeder), fireArrow(seeder),
           rydelsArrows(seeder), lrgAxe(seeder),
           medAxe(seeder), smallAxe(seeder),
           ironDwarfAxe(seeder);
}


int main()
{
    /***************************************************************************************************************
    ****************************************************************************************************************
    ** create variables, health points for Giants (attackers), Dwarfs and Elves (defenders)                       **
    ** damage taken, damage dealt,                                                                                **
    ** speed, attack speed                                                                                        **
    ** and weapons used & range of attack                                                                         **
    ****************************************************************************************************************
    ****************************************************************************************************************/

    std::cout << " *** Giants vs Dwarfs and Elves *** " << std::endl;

    // random number output test
    for (int c = 0; c <= 250; c++)
    {
        std::cout << "number: " << rN(40, 80) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "--------" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
kind regards, Shane.

Comment: Post text, not pictures.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1):

There quite a few wrong things with your code, I suggest you read some introductory book to C++.

In the first example your function `int rN(int low, int high)` works, although the initialization of the generator may give some troubles but I'll address that later. Your problem here is that you are defining global variables as ints, when the program starts all those variables get a random number and then that number remains constant for the rest of the program.

The `rN` in your second example does not what you expect at all, you are using syntax from other languages that for some extraordinary chance happens to compile in C++ ;) first when you do `club(min = 40, max = 80)` you are assigning 40 to the variable `min`, which returns itself which is passed as parameter; the passed value is 40, that's right but you are also changing the value of `min` for the rest of the function. Then you are returning a single int (as you put in the function signature), all those commas in the return are the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) you are actually just returning the last one. And as for why are you always getting the same number my bet goes to your initialization with `time(NULL)`, you initialize the generator every time you enter the function so if you enter the function faster than the time is updated you reinitialize with the same value and therefore you get the same output. Making `static std::mt19937 seed(time(NULL));` fixes that but still not the best way of initializing it.

The proper way to initialize the random number engine is to feed it with a `std::seed_seq` of the size of the internal state of the engine (`std::mt19937::state_size`), either fill the sequence with fixes values (so every run you get same result) or with `std::random_device`. Although I see this is a bit overkill for your level of C++.

Anyway, I didn't meant to discourage you, keep on it, setting challenges to yourself is the best way to learn :)